# gmock how to specify that no other mocking methods should ever be called?

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have a mock class which currently has three methods being mocked:

```
MOCK_METHOD0(method1, std::string());
MOCK_METHOD1(method2, bool(std::string str));
MOCK_METHOD1(method3, bool(std::string str));
...
```

In one test case I expect that method1 is only called once on mockClass and no other mocking methods should be ever called by specifying Times(0).

```
{
    InSequence sequence;
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockClass, method1(_)).WillOnce(doSomething());
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockClass, method2(_)).Times(0); 
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockClass, method3(_)).Times(0); 
}
```

However, if the number of mocking methods is very large on the mock class, I would have to write a lot of .Times(0) on these mocking methods that I don't expect them to be called.

I think if I omit all these .Times(0), google test will print uninteresting mock function calls to the console, but these are warnings rather than errors and they are difficult to catch. Is there an easy way that I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StrictMock` - see this [link](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#the-nice-the-strict-and-the-naggy) for more documentation on different mock variants.